# c# object list filtering (linq?)

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects `IEnumerable<Item>`, lets call it Items. Item has a propoerty `Item.Subitems` which is a list of subitems. List is about 500 items, with avg 10 subitems each.

Those are all "in memory" objects (theres no db querying at this level).

I would like to have a function:

```
public static string GetSubitemValue( int id )
{
  return Items.SelectMany( i => i.Subitems ).FirstOrDefault( si => si.id == id).Value;
}
```

function `GetSubitemValue` will be called multiple times (lets assume 500) during one process call (this a part o Razor view rendering process).

Are there any build-in linq enhancements that would support repeatable list search (iteration?). Should i care to do some caching or indexing on my own?

Comment: First you should ask yourself: Does it have any impact at all or am I doing premature optimization? If it *does* have an impact, cache the items an a Dictionary, HashMap or something similar.

Comment: In the case of you, i have some suggest: using redis cache or memcache.

Comment: Thanks @Linh but i have no ability to extend solution at this level. I only have access to Model at view level (Razor). Items list is part of Model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no built-in mechanic to enhance multiple sorts. However, you could implement caching of return values as follows.

```
private static Dictionary<int,string> Cache = new Dictionary<int,string>();

public static string GetSubitemValue(int id)
{
    if (!Dictionary.Contains(id))
    {
        Dictionary[id]
            = Items.SelectMany(i => i.Subitems)
                   .FirstOrDefault(si => si.id == id).Value;
    }
    return Dictionary[id];
}
```

However, note that your initial code snippet throws an exception if `Items` does not contain the desired id.